# Regular expression to ignore each first and second word of a selected sentence

Tags: html, regex, selection

I want to create a Regular expression to ignore each first and second word of a selected sentence

For example I have this phrase "**October 27 New Store Products / October 2022**". I want to create a regex that will choose only this part of the phrase ~ "**New Store Products / October 2022**" and ignore the first date part of the phrase ~ "**October 27**".

Comment: JavaScript? PHP? Ruby? Python? ASP? HTML doesn't have any form of regex, so we need some more information please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowledge of your true requirements, all we can do is provide best guess, so here is mine;

What you could do, is have something such as the following;

```
/^\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)$/
```

What this would do is the following;
From the beginning of the string (`^`), find one or more non-whitespace chars (`\S+`), find one or more whitespace chars (`\s+`) - repeat this again and then use a capture group (`(.*)`) to get everything else until the end of the string (`$`).

If you are using JavaScript, you could use this as such;

```js
let sentence = "October 27 New Store Products / October 2022";
let regex = /^\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)$/;
let match = regex.exec(sentence);

if (match) {
  // Ignores the first and second words of the sentence
  console.log(match[1]); // Output: "New Store Products / October 2022" ignoring "October 27"
}
```

---

Further explanation of this regex taken from [regex101](https://regex101.com/)<sup>1</sup> when this is put into the regex bar

> `/^\S+\s+\S+\s+(.*)$/`
>
> `^` asserts position at start of the string
> `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
> `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
> `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
> `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
> `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> 1st Capturing Group `(.*)`
> `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

---

<sup>1</sup> Emphasis mine

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided any information on the context, but does it need to be a regular expression?

String manipulation by searching on spaces might be easier.

For example in PHP:

```
$string = "October 27 New Store Products / October 2022";
$string_array = explode(' ', $string, 3);
if (array_key_exists(2, $string_array)) echo $string_array[2];
```

or Excel:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))
```